# Cómo unir dos tablas en un CTE?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, tablas, vistas

Quisiera unir un CTE con una tabla, pero no sé cómo podría hacerlo
Tengo el siguiente cto

```
with cte
as (
    select -1 n
    union all select n + 1 from cte where n < 369

)

select dateadd(month, n, convert(date, getdate())) dt from cte order by dt  option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Y tengo la siguiente tabla

```
Select cadena, detalle saldo from DeudaAux2
```

Cómo pudiera unir las dos, para que después puede crear una lista

Quisiera que quede así

Date|saldo

Comment: Hola. No se entiende por qué haces referencia al `cte` dentro de la definición del CTE (Common Table Expression), ni idea qué es un CTO. Tampoco se entiende qué relación tiene deudaAux2 con el contenido del cte. Si logras [edit] la pregunta y explicar mejor la situación añadiendo toda la info relevante, posiblemente recibas ayuda rápidamente

Comment: @Alfabravo ya corregí lo de "CTO", en cuanto el cte, encontré ese scrips aquí en el foro, y me sirve para hacer una lista de fechas mensuales, lo que quiero es cruzarla con esa tabla de deudaAux2, que si es verdad no tiene relación, pero quería ver si se podría relacionar de todas formas

Comment: @Alfabravo se trata de un CTE recursivo. Sin embargo, es poco recomendable usarlo porque afecta el rendimiento.

Comment: Me queda claro lo que haces con el CTE, pero no sé que contiene la otra consulta y como lo estarías uniendo. ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: @LuisCazares el valor más importante de la otra tabla sería el "saldo" que vendría siendo un decimal, lo que quiero es lograr, hacer un listado mensual con ese saldo ...cómo dije en mi anterior comentario no exite relación alguna entre el CTE y la tabla..por lo que no sabría cómo unir las dos cosas